# Firestore managing auto increment ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My application will have multiple users and they will be feeding complaints and getting back **complaint ID's**.

I have created a separate document which stores the latest incremental values, every time a complaint is saved, **it firsts gets the maximum number** from that document  , increments it with **+ 1** and saves that **complaint ID** in new complaint document.

Users will be around 8, is this possible that this **autoincrement** number can be duplicated?

Just in case, attaching screenshot of console and copying my code

[image]

```
  get_ticket_id(){
    //1. check if the doc exists
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('complaints').doc("autoincrement");
docRef.get().then(async doc=> {
if (doc.exists) {
    this.ticketnumber = doc.data().number + 1;
 await   firebase.firestore().collection("complaints").doc("autoincrement").update({
      number: this.ticketnumber,
    })
    .then(async doc=> {
   await    this.CreateNewComplaint();
    })

} else {
```

Am I following the best practice? Please note: I am not using `increment` option

`const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);`
`number: increment`

**Is it safer to use increment ?**

### Edit 1

Use transactions as guided, I am trying to fetch the value of `newIncId` in a variable but it says, code unreachable on this code of line `this.ticketnumber = newIncId;  // code uncreable`.

```
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('complaints').doc("autoincrement");
    firebase.firestore().runTransaction(transaction=> {
      return transaction.get(docRef).then(incDoc=> {
    
          //if no value exist, assume it as 0 and increase to 1
          var newIncId = (incDoc.data().number || 0) + 1;
    
          transaction.update(docRef, { number: incDoc });
          return newIncId;
          this.ticketnumber = newIncId;  // code uncreable
    
      });
    }).then(function(newIncId) {
...//some code
```

### Edit 2

Giving this error:

`Function Transaction.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom t object (found in field number)`

Attaching screenshot of console

[image]

Comment: Here is your umpteenth reminder that the quote block device (`>`) is for quotes. Your wilful use of it as a general highlighter is semantically incorrect no matter how many times you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to use transaction and get the new number:

```js
var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('complaints').doc("autoincrement");

db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    return transaction.get(docRef).then(function(incDoc) {

        //if no value exist, assume it as 0 and increase to 1
        var newIncId = (incDoc.data().number || 0) + 1;

        transaction.update(docRef, { number: newIncId });
        return newIncId;

    });
}).then(function(newIncId) {
    //`newIncId` This is your new number incremented

    //use newIncId here
    this.ticketnumber = newIncId;

    console.log("New autoincremented number ", newIncId);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Catch block to get any error
    console.error(err);
});
```

See doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions

---

Why you're not using `number: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);`?

This use transactions internally. But be aware that firestore document have the write limit of 1/sec. You can use RTDB if you expect to write more than once.

Comment: i want to have the incremented number value, how can i get that ?

Comment: Updated using transactions

Comment: what is RTDB, can you guide more on this please

Comment: updated my question, see `Edit 1`, i am trying to fetch the value of newIncId in a variable but it says, code unreachable

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: RTDB is firebase Realtime Database, which support write frequency of more than 1/sec.

Comment: error again - Function Transaction.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom t object (found in field number) ,  updated question , see `Edit::2`

Comment: Updated. `{ number: newIncId }` is correct.

Comment: @hkchakladar: you are welcome to help as much as you wish, but my advice is to encourage the question author to ask a new question. There is a point where a question can be regarded as "done", especially if the supplementary questions start to drift away from the purpose of the original question.

Answer (score 3):

For events like these you should consider Firebase transactions which prevent unwanted behaviours like multiple concurrent overwrites/updates.

```
final DocumentReference sfDocRef = db.collection("complaints").document("autoincrement");

db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(sfDocRef);
        int newId = snapshot.getInt("number") + 1;
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, "number", newPopulation);

        // Success
        return null;
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success!");
    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
    }
});
```

I've copied the code directly from the firebase documentation, so haven't properly tested this.

You could read more about transactions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#java

Comment: i am looking at the doc, i'll come back